# Install any extension and site crashes and goes into maintenance mode, control panel also goes into maintenance mode

Tags: php, magento

I installed an extension and the site went into maintenance mode, when i tried to access control panel to delete the maintenance flag i realized control panel is also in maintenance mode. what do i do

Comment: delete the extension by ftp?

Comment: @SuperDJ, i tried that but it gave an error message, 'could not connect to server"

Comment: @AndiToby that could have several reasons. Like incorrect details, no rights etc. So you might ask your host about that

Comment: One of the oldest Magento questions in the book, use your sftp client to look for `maintenance.flag` in the Magento root folder and delete it. Magento will be in 503 maintenance mode every time you install a module and the install doesn't cleanup by deleting this file. This Magento administration question will be a duplicate question either here or over in magento.stackexchange where it belongs.

Comment: @SuperDJ@Fiasco Labs i have done that, and when i tried the site i got another error message "Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.". so i did this:Navigate to the "errors" folder.Change local.xml.sample to local.xml
i saw a list of crazy errors all over the Magento page 
Open magento/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php and looked for:
protected $_options = array(
'cache_dir' => 'null',
Change it to:
protected $_options = array(
'cache_dir' => 'tmp/',
Save it.then created a tmp folder in the root Magento folder.but still seeing an error message with a bunch of crazy codes

Answer (score 0):

I finally did it. After I deleted the the maintenance flag, I also had to delete the extension.